# Error en test feature para almacenar usuario, no deberia fallar

Tags: laravel, test

tengo este metodo del controlador de **usuarios**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    User::create($request->all());
    //return response()->json(null,200);
}
```

La ruta es un `resource`:

```
Route::resource('user', UserController::class);
```

Y el `test` que le estoy implementando es el siguiente:

```
   public function testUserCreate()
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();

        $data = [
            'name'=>$faker->name(),
            'email'=>$faker->email(),
            'password'=>$faker->password()
        ];
        $reponse = $this->post('user',$data);
        $reponse->assertStatus(200);

    }
```

El resultado que obtengo es:

```
 FAIL  Tests\Feature\UserTest
  ⨯ user create

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\UserTest > user create
  Expected status code 200 but received 500.
  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500.

  at proyecto\tests\Feature\UserTest.php:28
     24▕             'email'=>$faker->email(),
     25▕             'password'=>$faker->password()
     26▕         ];
     27▕         $reponse = $this->post('user',$data);
  ➜  28▕         $reponse->assertStatus(200);
     29▕
     30▕     }
     31▕ }
     32▕

  1   proyecto\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:61
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()


  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   0.52s
```

El tema es que no deberia fallar eso, pero no se porque me da error **500** en vez de **200**

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que realmente deberías usar es [postJson](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#testing-json-apis).

```
$reponse = $this->postJson('/user', $data);
$response->assertStatus(200); // Aunque la respuesta para crear suele ser [201].
```